# Primefaces Datatable header width:auto

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am developing a dynamic Datatable with Primefaces 5. I have set the table width to auto. This is really nice. My Column uses only the needed width, which is perfect. But I also use paginator and a Table header. So my table looks like this:
[image: Dynamic datatable with header]

```
<p:dataTable var="row"  
             editingRow="#{row.status == CommonConstant.ROWSTATUS_EDIT}" 
             tableStyle="width:auto"
             value="#{componentBean.componentData[componentId].lazyModel}"
             id="#{componentId}" 
             editable="true" scrollable="false" scrollHeight="100%"
             resizableColumns="true"
             paginator="true"
             paginatorPosition="top"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="10 25 50 100"
             lazy="true">
  <f:facet name="header">   
    <p:outputPanel style="text-align:right">  
      <h:commandLink rendered="#{fn:indexOf(componentBean.componentData[componentId].loadedData.actions, CommonConstant.ACTIONTYPE_EXCEL) >= 0}" >
        <img border="0" src="img/excel.png" width="24"/>
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="#{componentId}" fileName="#{appDialogId}" />
      </h:commandLink>

      <h:commandLink rendered="#{fn:indexOf(componentBean.componentData[componentId].loadedData.actions, CommonConstant.ACTIONTYPE_PDF) >= 0}">
        <img border="0" src="img/pdf.png" width="24"/>
        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="#{componentId}" fileName="#{appDialogId}"/>
      </h:commandLink>

    </p:outputPanel>    

    <p:outputPanel>
      <h:outputText value="#{componentBean.componentData[componentId].loadedData.appdialogid}" />
    </p:outputPanel>                                              
  </f:facet>
...
</p:dataTable>
```

How can I force the Header and the paginator to have the same width than the table?

Answer (score 9):

For plain data table try this:

```
.ui-datatable {
    display: table;
}

.ui-datatable table {
    table-layout: auto !important;
}
```

I haven't tried resizable or anything else yet.

Comment: The first half of this works well for me and fixes the problem by making the paginator the same width as the table. The latter half causes the table to essentially overflow:visible; which screws with horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Unfortunately I stopped working with PrimeFaces more than a year ago and I'm no longer able to help. My solution worked back when I posted it, with that particular version of PrimeFaces. It's possible that newer versions have brought changes that make my solution no longer applicable. I'm sorry I can't be of any assistance in this regard anymore.

Comment: No need, only saying that the former half is all I needed for this to work in PF 6.0.

Answer (score 3):

[image: The result of editing the styles on the showcase - see the space on the right.]

I am assuming you are setting the auto width on the datatable as I can recreate your problem.

Try this:

1. set the style to *min-width: $px* on the div with the *ui-datatable* class to a value that makes your table happy
2. remove the auto width from the table and add *table-layout: auto ! important* to the table element so the colums still auto size somewhat but relative to the header.

Note: The width on the table element needs to remain as 100%, its default, so it fills the header.

The below is not really relevant but still 'good to know'.

All datatables in Primefaces 5 use table-layout: fixed. You can override to match the older Primefaces model using css.

```
.ui-datatable table, .ui-datatable-resizable table {
    table-layout: auto !important;
}

.ui-datatable-scrollable table {
    table-layout: fixed !important;
}
```

Scrollable data-tables need to remain as fixed.

It may help if you remove the outputPanels and use the data exporter facet for the links. If you prefer the links in the header put them in a span.

[Priemfaces example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml)

```
<f:facet name="{Exporters}">
        <h:commandLink> ...
        </h:commandLink> ...
</f:facet>
```

Comment: Some how this doesn't work for me. If I use your settings, I get the same result.

Comment: What happens if you remove the exporter links and panel?

Comment: The paginator panel still have 100% width. I tried the `f:facet name="{Exporters}"` construct, but didn't see the exporter buttons anymore.

Comment: I can recreate your problem and fix it. Hope its what you want.

Comment: Thats great for to Small tables, it works fine for me. But now I have a problem with a table which is Bigger than the View. The paginator stays at 100% and the datatable get bigger. See the [link](http://s1.directupload.net/images/140807/3zmc8v9s.png)

Comment: If it a scrollable table it has to stay table-layout: fixed You will have to remove the table style change.

Comment: How can I apply this using a css class? styleClass="..." because this code is for all datatables.

Comment: Thnx @twinj you answer help me out ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your datatable in a panelGrid

```
<p:panelGrid id="forautowidth" columns="1">
    --- Data Table Here ---
</p:panelGrid>
```

This has a somewhat annoying box around the table, but that is a good deal better then the overshooting paginator. Plus it works well as the browser page size changes